# Ionic on Mobile + MySQL Server + PHP (XAMPP) on PC

Tags: php, mysql, ionic-framework, localhost

Hi I am currently learning Ionic Framework for hybrid mobile apps and I want to connect it to localhost server (XAMPP).

I am developing Ionic App on my PC through `ionic start myApp blank` and `ionic serve`.

I have a **php file** on my **htdocs** folder in **XAMPP** which serves as a **server-side** function to call/query in my MySQL database.
Well, it goes well in development saying that I am working Ionic App on my PC where XAMPP also installed.

But, when I try to `ionic cordova build` my Ionic App for debug deployment as **APK** file and install the APK on my Mobile device it is not working.

Well, I know the reason why.

- because of the link in my codes: **var link = 'http://localhost/api.php';**

**My questions:**

- How can I access the **PHP file** inside **localhost server XAMPP**
  on my PC when my **Ionic App** is already APK and installed on my
  Mobile Device?
- Can I use my PC IPv4 address (saying that PC and Mobile are connected
  on same WIFI) instead of localhost in **var link**?

I hope someone can give me a light on my dark room.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a way on how to connect to my PC localhost web server.

First, I tried to connect to my **WIFI IPv4 Address** using the command `ipconfig` on cmd. And I tried to connect to it, then it was a success. I was able to connect my Mobile App to my PC Localhost web server (XAMPP). But the problem is, whenever the WIFI restarts, the WIFI IPv4 Address changes because of my WIFI DHCP(from what I read).

So, I came up with a another solution to that. I set my WIFI IPv4 address in my PC's Control Panel/Network and Internet/Network Connections and edit the WIFI IPv4 Address, instead of automatically assigned, I changed it to **static**. Whenever my WIFI device restarts, it does not change my PC WIFI IP address.

So, that's how my problem solved. But I think there will be a problem sooner when theres a same WIFI IPv4 address assigned to other connected device on the WIFI. But, it is okay for now. I am glad that I can access my MySQL database on XAMPP in my PC from my Mobile Device and able to query data.

Thanks. I hope this can solve the problem of other people who has similar problem of mine. Happy coding.